# "requestAnimationFrame". Trigger for click is ignored in "requestAnimationFrame"

Tags: javascript

In overall I have following code(it is more complex in source, so I just left problematic part):

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    var input = window.document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "file";
    input.click();
});
```

It opens file browse dialog, but if I use "requestAnimationFrame" wrapper, then it fails to open file browse dialog in Chrome.

I know that I can use "setTimeout" instead of "requestAnimationFrame".
Example - https://jsfiddle.net/t92L6vh5/
Is there any other workaround for this?

Comment: Why do you need to do this inside a RAF or setTimeout in the first place?

Comment: Whole scenario is following:
1. User can define his own js script;
2. When we run user defined script - we should show loading animation;
3. User defined scripts could freeze js thread;
4. CSS GPU Animation like "animate transform" runs in different thread and we can display this loading/execution animation;

In result to display this animation - I need run user defined script using "requestAnimationFrame". I can use "setTimeout", but it does not work stable as "requestAnimationFrame".
And in result user defined script can contains such thing as "input.click()"

Comment: Same behavior on my FF, gets blocked as a popup, even when the site is allowed... Dunno why though. And FF even blocks when [in a message event](https://jsfiddle.net/3jvpuy16/) (smallest timeout available), while chrome doesn't...

Comment: That's a neat finding, but for your issue, you might get better results by asking how to get the same result without this rAF call. (Why is so important that it gets called at screen refresh? rAF will be of no help with scripts that take more than 16ms anyway.)